# Error in starting the lite-server using NPM

Tags: node.js, json, npm, node-modules, angular-fullstack

> npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
>
> npm ERR! file C:\Users\thehitmanranjan\Desktop\git-test\package.json
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 240 while
>   parsing '{
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse "name": "git-test",
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse "version": "1.'
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
>
> npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just
>   JavaScript.

This is the error I get when I give command "npm start".
My package.JSON file has the following contents:

```
{

"name": "git-test",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "\"This is a test directory to learn Git and Node\"",

"main": "index.html",

"scripts": {

"start":"npm run lite",

"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"

"lite":"lite-server"

},

"repository": {

"type": "git",

"url": "git+https://github.com/thehitmanranjan/git-test.git"

},

"author": "Pratik Ranjan",

"license": "ISC",

"bugs": {

"url": "https://github.com/thehitmanranjan/git-test/issues"

},

"homepage": "https://github.com/thehitmanranjan/git-test#readme",

"devDependencies": {

"lite-server": "^2.5.4"

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comma missing after this line `"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"`

Answer (score -1):

Also, if that doesn't work, try renaming your `package.json` to `package.json.old` and re-doing `npm init`. It solved my problem. I was going crazy for hours trying to figure it out.